# red5 deployement

Tags: java, deployment, javabeans, red5

i m trying to deploy red5 server and having the following error. Can anyone help me out here.

```
[INFO] [main] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol - Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-0.0.0.0-5080
[INFO] [main] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol - Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-0.0.0.0-5080
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader - Dedicated RTMPT server configuration was not specified
[INFO] [main] org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader - Dedicated RTMPS server configuration was not specified
Bootstrap complete
Exception in thread "Launcher:/__MACOSX" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Could not resolve bean definition resource pattern [/WEB-INF/red5-*.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:458)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:388)
        at org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader$1.run(TomcatLoader.java:594)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getURL(ServletContextResource.java:132)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.isJarResource(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:414)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:343)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:282)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getResources(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1156)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:177)
        ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening as definition of bean was not found by red5. Only to restore the `web-inf` file did the trick also `keystore` was restored to its original one for red5.